# Can't read JSON data from client (webpage) with Arduino Leonardo ETH

Tags: arduino-leonardo, json

I'm reading a digital pin and count how many times that pin is enable, after that the data is sent in JSON format. All is working well till here. But I want to introduce a value from webpage to arduino, so the arduino will know from what number it should count. I modified the webpage, I'm converting the value in JSON format, everything. But I can't get it on arduino. I see the value on Serial Monitor right before client disconnect. But I just cannot figure what I'm doing wrong, maybe you guys have a suggestion ?

Here is my Arduino code ( is a bit messy, and I haven't did the part were I tell to arduino the number where it should start to count, I will do that after i can get my numbers from webpage ). If needed i can also add the webpage code.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

int pin = 3;
int state = 0;
//==========================
int push = 0;
//==========================
int laststate = 0;
const int chipS = 4;

byte mac[] = {0x00, 0x08, 0xDC, 0x1C, 0xB8, 0x4C}; // Enter the MAC address that is on your Ethernet shield (sticker) - eg. 00-08-DC-1C-B8-4C  (but use hexidecimal format eg. 0x00)
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 88);                     // The IP address that you will give the Server - will depend on your local network range
EthernetServer server(8880);                       // The port to listen for Web Browsers - the default is 80, but some routers will block this port.. so change to 8081.

//*************************************************************************************************
// setup function
//=================================================================================================
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // Begin Serial communication (baud rate = 9600).
    while (!Serial)
    {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip); // Initialise the ethernet library and network settings: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin
    server.begin();          // Tell the server to begin listening for incoming connections (on port 8081 in this example)
    Serial.print("Server IP address : ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP()); // If you see the IP address within the Serial monitor - you know that the server started successfully
    Serial.println(" ");

    // cardlaif  -  SD CARD INITALIZATION
    Serial.println("Initializare card...");
    if (!SD.begin(chipS))
    {
        Serial.println(" Initializarea cardului a esuat sau cardul lipseste ");
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    Serial.println(" Card initializat ");
    Serial.println(" ");
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

//*************************************************************************************************
// loop function
//=================================================================================================
void loop()
{
    //=====================================================================================================
    // contor  PIN 3 COUNTER
    //======================================================================================================
    state = digitalRead(pin);

    if (state != laststate)
    {
        if (state == HIGH)
        {
            push++;
        }
        delay(50);
    }
    laststate = state;

    Serial.print(" nr. citiri: ");
    Serial.println(push);
    //====================================================================================================
    // card SD CARD WRITE CODE
    //====================================================================================================
    String dataString = " ";
    dataString += String("nr. citiri: ");
    dataString += String(push);

    File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    if (dataFile)
    {
        dataFile.println(dataString);
        dataFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
    }
    //========================================================================================================
    //    net
    //========================================================================================================
    EthernetClient client = server.available(); // assign any newly connected Web Browsers to the "client" variable.

    if (client.connected())
    {
        Serial.println("Client Connected");
        // char c = client.read();
        // Serial.print(c);
        while (client.available())
        {
            Serial.write(client.read()); // Uncomment if you want to write the request from the Browser (CLIENT) to the SERIAL MONITOR (and comment out the next line)
            // client.read();                               // This line will clear the communication buffer between the client and the server.
        }

        // Send the Server response header back to the browser.
        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));                                                                                           // This tells the browser that the request to provide data was accepted
                                                                                                                                        //    client.println("GET");
        client.println(F("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"));                                                                            // Tells the browser it has accepted its request for data from a different domain (origin).
        client.println(F("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"));                                                // The arduino will accept JSON format data using this
        client.println(F("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With")); // The arduino will accept JSON format data using this
        client.println(F("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"));                                                              // Lets the browser know that the data will be in a JSON format
        client.println(F("Server: Arduino"));                                                                                           // The data is coming from an Arduino Web Server (this line can be omitted)
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));                                                                                         // Will close the connection at the end of data transmission.
        client.println();                                                                                                               // You need to include this blank line - it tells the browser that it has reached the end of the Server reponse header.

        // Example Transmission: [{"key":0, "value":300},{"key":1, "value":320},{"key":2, "value":143},{"key":3, "value":24},{"key":4, "value":760},{"key":5, "value":470}]
        client.print("[");            // This is tha starting bracket of the JSON data
        client.print("{\"value\": "); // The value I read on pin 3 and send in JSON format to webpage
        client.print(push);           //  The value I read on pin 3 and send in JSON format to webpage
        client.print("}");            //  JSON things
        client.println("]");          // This is the final bracket of the JSON data
    }

    //=================================================================================================
    // trying to print on serial json data
    //=================================================================================================
    char json[] = "{\"index\" }";
    StaticJsonBuffer<300> jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject &root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    if (!root.success())
    {
        Serial.println("Parsing failed");
    }
    int index = root["index"];
    Serial.print(" index: ");
    Serial.print(index);
    Serial.println(" ");

    client.stop();                       // This method terminates the connection to the client
    Serial.println("Client has closed"); // Print the message to the Serial monitor to indicate that the client connection has closed.
} // VOID LOOP END
```

And this is what I get on serial monitor:

```
Client Connected
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.88:8880
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8,es;q=0.7

5 index: 0
```

At the end, that 5 before the " index " word should be where the 0 is.
The 5 it's my JSON data. The reason why I see it it's because I enabled to see the reqest from the browser.

Someone have any idea ?

P.S Sorry for my bad english ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Below, you create a static string, which is never used again.

```
char json[] = "{\"index\" }";
```

Here you create a buffer and instantiate an empty JsonObject.

```
StaticJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
```

Here you check if `root` (your newly created JsonObject) is valid. Because it's empty and fresh, it is valid.

```
if (!root.success())
{
  Serial.println("Parsing failed");
}
```

Here, you try to ask for the value of `index` from your empty object.

```
int index = root["index"];
Serial.print(" index: ");
Serial.print(index);
```

If you never provide the `JsonObject` with any structure or content to parse, how can it give you anything back besides nothing?

The examples from the ArduinoJSON library prove to be helpful:

[Documentation on `parseObject`](https://arduinojson.org/api/jsonbuffer/parseobject/)

> ```
> char json[] = "{\"hello\":\"world\"}";
> StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
> JsonObject& object = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
> const char* world = object["hello"];
> ```

Note the differences from what you are doing:

1. The initial JSON string to parse has both a key and a value.
2. The `StaticJsonBuffer` declaration includes a buffer size
3. The `JsonObject` declaration uses `parseObject` and passes in the `json` string, instead of creating a blank/empty object.